# What I need to setup netbeans for broadleaf commerce with glassfish 4.1?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, netbeans-8, glassfish-4, broadleaf-commerce

I tried broadleaf with eclipse but it still gives more errors and I am familiar with netbeans and glassfish i setup the mysql server and created  new schema. I don't know how to create tables broadleaf does not provided schema creation file. Can broadleaf project automatically creates tables.also imported that eclipse project into netbeans project, tried to maven install and tried to run single-single modules, like first I run admin module and if all modules needs to run simultaneously so how can I? when I try to run admin module it gives following errors

```
Warning:   Unable to load class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.UserProvider, reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Set web app root system property: 'blAdmin.root' = [/home/yogesh/Documents/eclipse-workspace/DemoSite/admin/target/admin/]
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing log4j from [/home/yogesh/Documents/eclipse-workspace/DemoSite/admin/target/admin/WEB-INF/log4j.xml]
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Info:   [ WARN] 19:32:15 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
Info:   [ WARN] 19:32:17 MergeXmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.concurrent.Executor org.broadleafcommerce.common.event.BroadleafApplicationEventMulticaster.taskExecutor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler] for bean with name 'blNullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/yogesh/Documents/eclipse-workspace/DemoSite/admin/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/core-1.0.jar!/com/mycompany/sample/vendor/nullPaymentGateway/web/processor/NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_80
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:661)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:471)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.concurrent.Executor org.broadleafcommerce.common.event.BroadleafApplicationEventMulticaster.taskExecutor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler] for bean with name 'blNullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/yogesh/Documents/eclipse-workspace/DemoSite/admin/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/core-1.0.jar!/com/mycompany/sample/vendor/nullPaymentGateway/web/processor/NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_80
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /admin
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.concurrent.Executor org.broadleafcommerce.common.event.BroadleafApplicationEventMulticaster.taskExecutor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler] for bean with name 'blNullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/yogesh/Documents/eclipse-workspace/DemoSite/admin/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/core-1.0.jar!/com/mycompany/sample/vendor/nullPaymentGateway/web/processor/NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class com.mycompany.sample.vendor.nullPaymentGateway.web.processor.NullPaymentGatewayTRExtensionHandler has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_80
```

And when I tried to run site `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`

if using netbeans and glassfish for broadleaf is good idea or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Broadleaf documentation is quite elaborated. Try following [Broadleaf Getting Started.](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started)

Once you setup your project as mentioned in this link, try running your site first and your database will be created with all the tables.

You don't need to import any schema as such, running site for the first time automatically creates your database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about netbeans and glassfish